# SQLite Foreign Key Constraint Not Throwing Error

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am following this guide: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

But when I try it for myself it does not give an error:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE artist(
   ...>   artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>   artistname  TEXT
   ...> );
sqlite> CREATE TABLE track(
   ...>   trackid     INTEGER,
   ...>   trackname   TEXT,
   ...>   trackartist INTEGER,
   ...>   FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT INTO track (trackid, trackname, trackartist) VALUES (1, 'Me', 1);
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreign Key support must be enabled through the command `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`